# Relay RootContainer's "renderFetched" vs "Component"

Tags: relay

In Relay,

The RootContainer accepts 2 props called "renderFetched" and "Component".

Their description sounds similar. What exactly is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1):

"renderFetched" is a callback that passes the data to the "Component"

*When all data requirements are fulfilled, renderFetched is called to render the view. This callback is expected to spread data into the supplied Container when rendering it.* [ref.](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-root-container.html#renderfetched)

I suppose the purpose of this function is to do some transformation to the data before passing it to the Component.